# Braintree create subscription with dynamic price

Tags: braintree, laravel-cashier

I am building a donation page where I want the user to decide the amount and frequency of the donation for hisself.

I looked up in the [Braintree documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/php), and I couldn't find out if and how to pass the amount of the subscription.

I am asking now how can I override the amount of the subscription. I am using Cashier/Braintree.

Should I apply them in the add-ons?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, contact [support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact)</sub>

You can change the default price of a subscription by passing the [`price`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/php#price) parameter in your [`Subscription.create()`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/php) API request. This will override the default price set by the [plan](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/plans) you've configured. As an example, your API request may look something similar to this if you wanted to change the price of a single subscription to $20:

```
$result = $gateway->subscription()->create([
  'paymentMethodToken' => 'the_token',
  'planId' => 'the_plan_id',
  'price' => '20'
]);
```

I've found that it is much easier to manage the price of subscriptions by using this method, however, you may also find it easier to use add-ons instead. If you choose to use add-ons, you'll need to [create each add-on in the Control Panel](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/add-ons-discounts).

Comment: David, after you've created an add-on, the documentation is not clear about how do you created a subscription with the add-on. Does the plan_id simply become the add-on plan_id?